# Pearson $\chi^2$ residuals vs deviance

Tags: generalized-linear-model, model-selection, deviance

In a GLM, how should I interpret the difference between using

1. sum of the model's *Pearson residuals*
2. model's *Deviance*

to assess the fit of my model? Is the former more "flexible" since I can estimate a dispersion parameter? I feel like the *Deviance* provide a more parametric assessment since it takes the form of the ML equations we're using to fit the model whereas the Pearson residuals feel one step removed. Is this right / which is more "parametric"?